# On meta sites, require at least one non-required tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, per-site-meta, required-tags

A question with just a required tag isn't really a tagged question. [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) doesn't really explain what topics the discussion is about... it's basically a meta tag. A useful meta tag, but quite not enough tagging.

Whenever I see [a meta question with just the one tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3887/revisions) on Meta Gaming, [I always try to add a second tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2694/revisions), but it would be nicer if it was the asker who did this.

Comment: You might want to make it a [second, non-"required" required tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+discussion+support).

Comment: I've seen people edit my questions before to add additional tags beyond [discussion].  I'm always amused by that, and additional categorization is fine, but what problem is actually being solved that requires forcing additional tags, other than to satisfy someone's sensibilities about how questions on Meta should be categorized?  Perhaps if you made that clearer, @Yannis.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's the same logic that leads you to tag questions on Stack Overflow to begin with. A question tagged [tag:discussion] is pretty much as tagged as a question tagged [tag:untagged].

Comment: Where's @GraceNote when you need her?

Comment: As long as you don't call it required and non-required... there must be a better term!

Comment: The answers at [Should we prevent meta questions from only containing required tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320543/should-we-prevent-meta-questions-from-only-containing-required-tags) are better and more relevant to this question, including a method of enforcing this as a community.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that on the "Ask a question" page there should be check boxes for the mandatory required "meta"-tags and then the "tags" line would have to contain at least one "regular" tags.
This features require a check that a "meta" tag is not inserted as a regular tag.

Comment: People know how the tag area looks like and how to use it, why introduce something new?

Comment: @tohecz I think that meta tagging is a little different than regular tags and therefore there is room for considering new layout.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've posted questions with just the discussion tag on MSU before. In fact, a good chunk of them *just* have one tag, since its all I need - if its to do with [general site policy](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5720/whats-the-right-flag-if-a-link-has-malware), or what [we need to do with a single specific tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5114/the-khanacedemy-tag-yay-nay-or-burninate). I don't see either of them being any clearer with an additional tag, personally.

I've also used [specific additional tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3742/can-i-promise-a-bounty-but-only-put-it-in-place-once-there-is-an-acceptable-ans) when I've wanted to do something that didn't *quite* fit the way things were usually done, and the second tag would help others find it

I really think this is yet another one of these things I feel should be organic to the site - it isn't a major thing to fix, and in quite a few cases, the additional tag might be somewhat localised. I don't really think there's any advantage to having a compulsary need for an additional, non mandatory tag

Comment: Of course _you_ don't need any more tags on _your_ questions, you know what they are about. Now tell me, how can I find all general policy questions on MSU, without having to dig through a ton of discussions I couldn't care less about? You have a [policy tag](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/policy), use it.

Comment: I'd note, quite to my amusement, that additional entirely valid tags have been added. While I still hold my ground on my viewpoint that making them compulsary is un-necessary, I'm amused, and think this is a great way to make a point. It also so happens that these tags were added in by a member of the community, and I would never have thought of adding those tags. Its made my answers better. Thank you!