# require multiple tags (or some tags are not sufficient)

Tags: feature-request, tags

Some tags, by themselves, are not sufficient and produce really poor 'related questions' links.  Questions tagged with just these tags tend to be poor and indicate a lack of thought and/or commitment by the asker.

The request: Add a property to some tags to indicate 'this tag alone is not a sufficient tag for the question'.  The 'not sufficient' property on a tag would be managed by the moderators of the site.

For example, on meta, the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is not enough tagging to indicate the nature of the question being asked <sub><sup>(I do realize on meta these tags have additional properties of being required tags, and meta specific has its own question: [On meta sites, require at least one non-required tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121243/on-meta-sites-require-at-least-one-non-required-tag))</sup></sub>.  On SO, this is particularly evident with questions that are tagged with only a language, though the problem exists on other sites too.

I realize that the side effect of this could be people typing in the subject into the tags section and hoping to get something.  This is not *worse* than it is now with only a single tag.  New users won't have the privileges necessary to create new tags.

Various advantages:

- Larger dup hammer possibilities.  Instead of just a 'java' tag, there's also a 'mysql' tag in there.
- Better chance of having something meaningful in the tags allowing for more useful similar questions (if not for the OP, for the *next* person who comes across the question)

  - This is related to the 'relevancy' aspect of super-mega-high voted questions for a given tag.  For example a question tagged `php` (credit card masking) or `java` (something about text area) or `javascript` (decode this javascript for me):

    [image: php credit card masking] [image: Text area do not append][image: javascript]

    Note that the high voted question in the related question bears no resemblance to the asked question other than that it is about php in the first example and java in the second and javascript in the third.  This can often be seen in questions with single tags <sub><sup>(the regex related questions is particularly useless on SO because everything is just single tag... but that's another matter)</sup></sub>.

    The nature of this serves to further propagate unnecessary up votes to the questions because of their already existing high visibility... but that's another matter too.

Comment: Can you give an example of a tag that you *would* consider to be sufficient?

Comment: @mmyers its the *combination* of tags that is needed.  Most languages would likely require an additional tag.  On the other hand, `eclipse` or `chromecast` or `curl` *may* be enough to fully tag the question.  However, `java`, `php`, `javascript` rarely are enough - these tags often need additional tags to properly describe the focus of the question.

Comment: Is there a correlation between such tags and the highly used ones? For instance [discussion] here is used on some 30 % of questions.